# onBackPressed() not being executed

Tags: android

I'm implementing the onBackPressed() method in my activity. It's crucial to my app that I have this functionality. But, the control never enters this function. It enters onPause() instead, when I press the back button.

But the problem is I can't have the same logic in onPause() because when I call another activity, the current activity calls onPause() and I don't want it to execute what should be in onBackPressed().

Please help.

```
public void onBackPresed(){

   Log.d(TAG,"inside onBackPressed()");
       if(STATE == PREVIEW){

       } 
}
```

Comment: please post your code where you override the OnBackPressed method. Are you using the correct method header (params, return value) as the original one you want to override?

Comment: The code is above please check

Comment: Please try to crop your code a bit, we don't need to see all of it, just the override point, as Mathias said. If you want people to answer your questions you should also take some time and mark some of the answers you've gotten on other questions as accepted, it's good SO-manners to do so. What version of Android are you running?

Comment: @Banang: point noted. I have marked some answers not all of them because I haven't been able to verify them as yet. As soon as I do, I'll definitely mark them as I always do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
public void onBackPresed(){
```

you typed one 's', it should be onBackPre**ss**ed()

Comment: This is why you should always use @Override. :)

Comment: I don't get it, didn't Eclipse give you a warning when you used one 's'?

Comment: No it wouldn't. He doesn't use @Override, therefore he can declare any other method as he likes and give it any other name.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I do it.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    Log.d(TAG,"Back key pressed");
    return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: oh. Is this better than onBackPressed(). Does one methos have an advantage over the other?
I think one advantage with this method, is when you're listening for key presses, you can use a switch case and include the back press too.

Comment: +1 This works on all API Levels. `onBackPressed()` works on API Level 5 or higher (that's Android 2.0+)

Answer (score 3):

Just a heads up, the Android developer's blog posted about overriding the back press and dealing with backwards compatibility [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html).