# confirm dialog returns false immediately

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

This is my code:

```
index.html:
    ...
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init();"></body>
    ...

main.js:
    function onBackPressed(e) {
        console.log("onBackPressed()");
        var answer = confirm("Do you want to exit?");
        console.log(answer);
        if (answer) {
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        }
    }
    function init() {
        ...
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackPressed, false);
        ...
    }
```

When I exit application first time, everything seems to be ok.
The problem is when I start application next time, confirmation dialog returns false immediately and dialog stay visible. So when I click "OK" nothing will happen.

Here is output from logcat:

```
04-11 16:16:26.444: D/PhoneGapLog(18356): onBackPressed()
04-11 16:16:26.444: D/PhoneGapLog(18356): file:///android_asset/www/main.js: Line 49 : onBackPressed()
04-11 16:16:26.444: I/Web Console(18356): onBackPressed() at file:///android_asset/www/main.js:49
04-11 16:16:26.584: D/PhoneGapLog(18356): false
04-11 16:16:26.584: D/PhoneGapLog(18356): file:///android_asset/www/main.js: Line 51 : false
04-11 16:16:26.584: I/Web Console(18356): false at file:///android_asset/www/main.js:51
```

Is this a bug in phonegap or android? Or I'm doing something wrong?

I use Nexus One with android 2.3.6 and phonegap 1.4.1 (version 1.5 have issue with backbutton event).

Comment: Show how onbackpressed() is executed - and have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3212253/295783

Comment: I have `onload="init()"` in body tag and in init function I have `document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackPressed, false);`. Function onBackPressed() contains above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PhoneGap, confirm is does an asynchronous callback. See the [api docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html#notification.confirm).

The variable *answer* will always be false because of the immediate return.

The code should look more like:

```
    // process the confirmation dialog result
function onConfirm(button) {
    alert('You selected button ' + button);
}

// Show a custom confirmation dialog
//
function showConfirm() {
    navigator.notification.confirm(
        'You are the winner!',  // message
        onConfirm,              // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
        'Game Over',            // title
        'Restart,Exit'          // buttonLabels
    );
}
```