# Javascript confirm dialog on Windows 8.1 Store App

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, windows-8.1

I am currently creating a Windows 8.1 Store App, using html5, bing maps, javascript, phonegap & jquery.

I have a button in my app which, when clicked, calls the following function

```
function resetFields() {  
    var svar;  
    var tryk = confirm("Are you sure!");  
    if (tryk === true) {  
        svar = "You pressed OK!";  
    } else {  
        svar = "You pressed Cancel!";  
    }  
    alert(svar);  
}
```

The function is called fine and I see the confirm dialog as one would expect. However, no matter which button is pressed, the result is the same - the dialog responds as if the 'cancel' button has been pressed.

I have tried `if (tryk === true)` and `if (tryk == true)` but the result is the same.

What am I missing?

Even `alert(confirm("Are you sure!"))` is returning 'undefined' so I think my answer lies deeper than the basic code.

Comment: what does `alert(tryk)` give you, seems like it is return something else besides a boolean value, or for some reason always returning false.

Comment: `alert(tryk)`  gives 'undefined'

Comment: Try entering some log statements in the `if else` block and see if the confirm dialog is actually responding to the `yes/no` events.

Comment: @Vivek Pradhan thanks for your suggestion. It seems that the variable `tryk` is not being populated with the results of the confirm dialog - clicking on the buttons is not creating a boolean result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just going through some PhoneGap documentation and because it is built around html5 and javascript with jquery support, it tends to over-ride certain elements that we would normally see in the browser to take advantage of the native device elements like a confirm dialog.

From the [Notification confirm api docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html#notification.confirm):

> Function notification.confirm displays a native dialog box that is more customizable than the browser's confirm function.

Now, I think the variable `tryk` is undefined probably because the request returns immediately as soon as any button is clicked on the confirm dialog and that's why you can't properly exploit the handler functions.

In the api docs, they have given a quick example which looks like:

```
 // process the confirmation dialog result
function onConfirm(button) {
    alert('You selected button ' + button);
}

// Show a custom confirmation dialog
//
function showConfirm() {
    navigator.notification.confirm(
    'You are the winner!',  // message
    onConfirm,              // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
    'Game Over',            // title
    'Restart,Exit'          // buttonLabels
    );
}
```

And the `showConfirm()` method can be triggered from any html element like so:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="showConfirm(); return false;">Show Confirm</a>
```

So I think you should stick to the implementation they have officially provided. I just stumbled upon another [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108023/confirm-dialog-returns-false-immediately) where it says that PhoneGap confirm actually does an asynchronous callback.

Comment: Thanks That worked perfectly. Also, thanks for linking to the original post so that I could upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function Fields1(){
   var svar;
    var tryk = confirm("Are you sure!");
     if (tryk === true) {
        svar = "You pressed OK!";
      } else {
       svar = "You pressed Cancel!";
    }
   alert(svar);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick='Fields1()'>Hai</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: May I know the reason fr down voting?

Comment: Yes you may. It was a mistake.

Comment: this is the same as setting the return of confirm to a variable and checking the variable. And for some reason he is getting undefined so either way it will trigger the false clause.

Comment: @JezD but logically I can't see any mistake. Is there any mistake please tell me..

Comment: @Kannan, i think he meant that the downvote was a mistake, meaning he meant to upvote.

Comment: @Kannan I can't see anything wrong with your suggestion. I tried it and the result was the same. The down vote was a mistake and has since been rectified.

Comment: @JezD I am update my answer. This code working on my browser. If still you can see any problem please clear your **cache** and check your error **console**

Comment: @kannan It is actually a Windows 8 Store app I am creating. The code works fine in a conventional web browser, but it is in the Windows 8 Store App where I am having the problem.